# How do ultralight helicopter like mosquito manage to fly without a swash plate?

Tags: helicopter

It doesn't seem to have a swash plate. Does pilot shift his weight like in a hang glider?

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure Mosquito has collective and cyclic -- it hovers well.

Comment: [This is the swashplate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epwrL.png), within the mast, at the level of the black belt

Comment: Why would someone downvote this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pictured helicopter is a Mosquito Air. It does have a swash plate, it's just not visible because it's inside the main mast. The swash plate is connected to the blades via pushrods in the hollow rotor shaft, which connect to the blades from above.

Comment: I be interested in building one if it had a more reliable engine.

Comment: No @JohnK, just no 

Comment: Hey I'm adventurous, as long as it's 4 stroke or turbine lol.

Comment: @JohnK There actually are turbine-powered Mosquitoes out there.

Comment: Yeah I know.  Too expensive.  It needs a 4 stroke that can match the p/w of the Rotax.

Comment: @johnK 600cc engines salvaged from superbikes?